# NestJS middleware firing on browser url change

Tags: express, nestjs

I am trying to figure out the best way to log all http requests from a NestJS application to a database. It seems middleware is the best option so my class looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
class LogsMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  private readonly logger = new Logger('HTTP');

  use(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    response.on('finish', () => {
      const { method, originalUrl } = request;
      const { statusCode, statusMessage } = response;
      const message = `${method} ${originalUrl} ${statusCode} ${statusMessage}`;
      return this.logger.log(message);
    });
    next();
  }
}
export default LogsMiddleware;
```

For some reason if I just change the url in the browser and don't actually send a request, the middleware gets called and I see responses in the console:

> [Nest] 2502  - 08/17/2022, 10:00:14 PM     LOG [HTTP] GET /users/3 400
> Bad Request
>
> [Nest] 2502  - 08/17/2022, 10:00:14 PM     LOG [HTTP] GET /users/ 304
> Not Modified

Is this some form of caching thats being trigger before I actually send the request? I tried adding this as well:

```
app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance().set('etag', false);
```

And I still get responses logged to the console:

> [Nest] 2552  - 08/17/2022, 10:06:54 PM     LOG [HTTP] GET /users/ 200
> OK
>
> [Nest] 2552  - 08/17/2022, 10:06:54 PM     LOG [HTTP] GET /users/2 200
> OK

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't send a request? How are you changing the URL? Does the `network` tab in the browser show a request being made?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I am using safari and when I have web inspector open it doesn't send the request but when I close the web inspector they get sent.